# Cordova backbutton - prevent backbutton goback to previous page without confirmation

Tags: cordova, quasar-framework, back-button-control

I am using the Quasar CLI version 0.15.20 which has the dialog $q.dialog for confirmation. I want to control the backbutton on android device not to go back to previous page if the user doesnt confirm to leave. I used this below function but it doesnt work. It keeps going back before the dialog pop up asking to leave the page. any idea how to prevent it?

```
backButton (e){
    e.preventDefault()
    if (this.$route.name === 'session-show') {
       this.$q.dialog({
           title: 'Warning',
           message: 'Are you sure you want to leave without save?',
           ok: 'Yes',
            cancel: 'Cancel'
        }).then(() => {
            this.$router.go(-1)
            this.$q.notify('Data is removed!')
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('stay in current page')
        })
    }
  }
```

and I used this to call the event

```
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.backButton, false)
```

Comment: Your function is it linked to `backbutton` event ?

Comment: yes it is. I used this document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.backButton, false) in created() in Quasar.  It worked if i set it to exit the app on homepage.